# Client-side validation in richfaces 3.3.x

Tags: java, validation, jsf, richfaces, client-side

Is there any way of building client-side validation for Richfaces 3.3.x?

I know that 4.0 version is going to support it but still I need to have it implemented along wiht 3.3.x branch version. I need something like [jsf-comp](http://jsf-comp.sourceforge.net/) but with additional support for dates. It would be lovely to reuse as much of stuff as possible (for example: `f:attribute`).

Is there any commonly used solution?
How about [Trinidad's](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad) own [Client-side Converters and Validators](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/clientValidation.html). Is it worth bothering and is integrating it with Richfaces sufficiently painless?

Comment: you should accept previous answers

Answer (score 1):

Richfaces comes with in-built jQuery. You can use jQuery/Javascript to perform client-side validation

Comment: Yes, and there seems to be the only option. I'd like to know if there's any *framework* to help me deal with that.

Comment: You can use a jQuery validation *framework*, like this one: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation